# Does anyone know when the revised RCA siddur is going to be released?

Tags: jewish-books, prayer-book

The new RCA siddur has not been released yet even though they announced (on their website) its publishing 5 years ago!

I contacted the RCA and they didn't respond.

Answer (score 7):

As of October 2018, the new Koren RCA siddur is ready and orders are open, see [here](https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/koren/new-releases-koren/siddur-avodat-halev.html), [here](https://www.korenpub.com/media/productattachments/files/l/o/look_inside_rca.pdf) for a sample of the contents and [here](https://www.korenpub.com/media/productattachments/files/r/e/revised_-_unique_features_-_rca_siddur_draft02.pdf) for a detailed description of the inside.

Answer (score 4):

The RCA has announced that it will be released in March of 2018. It is a partnership with Koren Publishers Jerusalem.

https://www.makorrishon.co.il/news/10159/
article about the siddur.

Comment: Siddur is now complete and for sale, see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69820/11501)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

The updated [information](https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/koren/new-releases-koren/siddur-avodat-halev.html) shows that it will be released August 1, 2018.

> Siddur Avodat HaLev
>
> The NEW RCA Siddur - Siddur Avodat HaLev is a full siddur for
>   Weekdays, Shabbat and Haggim.
>
> Five years in the making, this outstanding Siddur from the Rabbaim of
>   the Rabbinical Council of America features:
>
> Fully Contemporary translation
>
> New commentaries utilizing classic as well as contemporary Rabbinic and traditional sources
>
> Additional prayers for life-cycle events and the modern observance of Yom Ha'atzmaut and Yom HaShoah Yom Yerushalayim
>
> Complete Sefer Tehilim
>
> Supplementary essays by classic and contemporary Rabbis
>
> Appropriate female textual and grammatical formulations where needed
>
> Rabbi Basil Herring, Editor in Chief, in conjunction with other outstanding Rabbaim of the RCA
>
> The Siddur Avodat Halev is the new standard Siddur for RCA Synagogues
>   for generations!
>
> For Bulk orders, please contact sales@korenpub.com
>
> PREORDERS ONLY - Orders will not be processed until after August 1,
>   2018
>
> $34.95
>
> ISBN  9789653019362 Size  Standard Language   Hebrew/English Binding
>     Hardcover Nusah     Ashkenaz

Comment: Siddur is now complete and for sale, see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69820/11501)